# Constructing a planar shape with area $\pi^2$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Is there a planar shape which can be defined using only algebraic numbers and basic shapes (line, polygon, circle, parabola, etc.), which has an area of $\pi^2$?

(I know this isn't a well-posed question, but what I'm interested in is whether there is any "simple" geometric construction which has an area of $\pi^2$. You may restate the problem if you think there is a better way of phrasing it).

(Also, I would rather that the shape be constructed in a finite number of steps, so no limits...)

Comment: Since you're willing to allow some drawing instruments, what about an Archimedean spiral implemented as a thread unwinding from a spool?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang sorry, I don't understand. An Archimedean spiral is not a closed shape, so what is it's area? (How do you define it area?). Also, it's unbounded. How long a spiral do you need to take to get the required area of $\pi^2$?

Comment: The spiral isn't the entire construction; just asking about the "acceptability" of a particular tool. :)

Comment: I guess it's okay to use something like this "Archimedean spiral of length $s$ with the polar equation $r=a+b\theta$ ", where the algebraic parameters are $a$,$b$,$s$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By wrapping a thread around a circle, it's possible to mark off a segment of length $\pi$ as the circumference of a circle of unit diameter, then to construct a square of side $\pi$. For example:

[image: A thread wrapped around a circle to mark off a segment of length pi]

Similarly, using an Archimedean spiral $r = b\theta$, we can mark off a segment of length $2\pi b$ (the radial separation of successive windings), and then construct a square of side $\pi$ (by taking $b = \frac{1}{2}$, for example).

Along different lines, the region $a_{1} + b\theta \leq r \leq a_{2} + b\theta$ for $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$ (bounded by Archimedean spirals and segments whose endpoints are intersections of the spirals with the positive $x$-axis) has area
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \bigl[(a_{2} + b\theta)^{2} - (a_{1} + b\theta)^{2}\bigr]\, d\theta
  &= \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{2\pi} (a_{2} - a_{1})(a_{2} + a_{1} + 2b\theta)\, d\theta \\
  &= (a_{2} - a_{1}) \bigl[\pi(a_{2} + a_{1}) + 2b\pi^{2}\bigr].
\end{align*}

Taking $a_{1} = 0$, $a_{2} = 1$, and $b = \frac{1}{2}$, for example, gives a region of area $\pi + \pi^{2}$. The excess can be whittled away by removing disks, say, nine disks of radius $\frac{1}{3}$ centered on the the intersections of the Archimedean spiral $r = \frac{1}{2}(1 + \theta)$ with the rays making (constructible!) angles $\frac{\pi}{10}(2i+1)$, for $1 \leq i \leq 9$:

[image: A region of area pi-squared bounded by Archimedean spirals and circles]

Comment: Though these regions are perhaps legally within bounds, I'm not sure any of them Really Answers the Question....

Comment: I think this is a great answer. I won't mark it as a final answer yet, since I would like to see if the community finds a "simpler" answer. (Maybe I should have rephrased my question to be about compass and straightedge constructions, where the straightedge has marks on all algebraic numbers?... I'm sure if that's a good phrasing). If I see that there is no answer, I'll mark this one as an answer.

Comment: On a tangent, Petr [sic] Beckmann's [_A History of Pi_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_History_of_Pi) will probably interest you (if you don't already know it). On a different tangent, Ian Stewart (if memory serves) claims that the circle-and-compass restriction comes not from Euclid, but [Eutocius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eutocius_of_Ascalon). My offhand suspicion is there's no algebraic-ruler-and-compass construction of a plane region of area $\pi^{2}$, but I'd happily be proven wrong! (A Cartesian product of unit disks has $4$-volume $\pi^{2}$, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

No. If there were such a construction then $\pi^2$ and hence $\pi$ would be algebraic. but it's not.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number

Comment: But you may construct a circle with area $\pi$ easily. here: "a circle with radius 1", even though $\pi$ is not algebraic.

Comment: Since circles are apparently allowed, we can certainly construct a shape with area $\pi$ -- so an argument that basically says that you can't construct any transcendental area would seem not to match the problem.

Comment: You are right. So my answer isn't one. I'll leave it up for a while to prevent others from making the same mistake.